# drupal_http_request not responding with redirect_url

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://some.url/with/data.asp" id=form1 name=form1>
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="name1" value="value1">
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="name2" VALUE="value2">
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="name3" VALUE="value3">
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="name4" VALUE="value4">
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="name5" VALUE="value5">

    <input type="submit" value="GO" id=submit2 name=submit2>
</form>
```

Which I have to submit by using `drupal_http_request` since it has to be done in a redirect_form within a Drupal Commerce Checkout-flow.

```
$url = 'https://some.url/with/data.asp';

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

$data = array (
    'name1' => 'value1',
    'name2' => 'value2',
    'name3' => 'value3',
    'name4' => 'value4',
    'name5' => 'value5',
);

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'POST', http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
```

The response I get in return contains all information I need except for the `redirect_url`. It's not present in the response and by so I cannot use a `drupal_goto` for example to redirect my users to the paygate...

What did I miss? Or is `drupal_http_request` not the correct way to emulate above form? Maybe I should go with cURL?

Comment: Is this asp page supposed to take the data and send a `Location: ` header?

Comment: It's a form collection all information for processing an online payment, so yes :)